# Get all SharePoint groups to which a user belongs

Tags: 2013, powershell

I'm trying to get a list of all the groups that a user belongs to using this powershell code from http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2013/exploring-sharepoint-users-groups-and-security-using-powershell:

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Web http://server/sites/yoursite |
                                Where {$_.LoginName -LIKE "*|DOMAIN\USER"}

Get-SPSite -Limit All |
Select -ExpandProperty RootWeb |
Select -ExpandProperty SiteUsers |
Where { $user.UserLogin -EQ $_.LoginName } |
Select -ExpandProperty Groups |
Select Name, {$_.ParentWeb.Url}
```

I don't get any results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the following script and get the groups a user(s) belong to

```
$urlWeb = Get-SPWeb http://dev
Get-SPUser -Web $urlWeb | select UserLogin, @{name="SPGroups";expression={$_.Groups}} | ?{$_.UserLogin -like "*arna*"} | format-Table -auto
```

The output (in my environment) is

```
UserLogin        SPGroups
---------        --------
i:0#.w|myad\arna {Dev Owners, Dev Visitors}
```

Comment: I had to add "-limit all" to Get-SPUser but then it worked.